# Scala String Interpolation

Tags: scala

I am new to Scala and have read threads related to String Interpolation.

My requirement is that , I want to find the type of an expression, before actually evaluating the expression.
To make it clear:

```
val tesType = s"${{10 * Math.cos(0)+ 3}.getClass}"
```

This gives me the return type of the entire expression.

Is it possible to generalise this by replacing the actual expression by a variable containing the expression?
Something like:

```
val expression="10 * Math.cos(0)+ 3"
val tesType = s"${{expression}.getClass}"
```

Would something like this be possible or I am totally wrong in thinking in this direction?

Thanks

Comment: You want type of expression which is String, right ?

Comment: Yes, once iterpolated, I want it to check for functions inside the string and give the result type accordingly.In the above case, double

Comment: String interpolation happens at compile time, nothing interpreted here. Also, I'd use variables as soon as your type gets a bit more complicated.

Comment: @Reactormonk string interpolation in general does _not_ happen at compile time. That would require macros.

Comment: @0__ I think @Reactormonk referred to the fact that `s"some $foo"` will be replaced by something like `StringContext("some ").s(foo)` before actual compilation, but by the compiler.

Comment: @phg correct, and I believe it's a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to do with string interpolation. What you actually want to do is to compile scala code in runtime from string (file etc).

For ex twitter `Eval` library can be used for this purposes: 
https://eknet.org/main/dev/runtimecompilescala.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want the expression to be in a string, then see mst's answer (you can also use `scala-compiler` itself as a library, but its API is harder to use).

If you have an expression *as an expression*, you can do

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
def typeOfExpr[T: TypeTag](t: => T) = typeOf[T]

typeOfExpr(10 * Math.cos(0)+ 3) // returns Double
```